# 2 WARs in maven EAR build

Tags: maven, web, war, ear

I am new to maven and as a matter of fact new to the build tools and process or should i say the whole web structure. I have a slight problem for which i need help.

I am going to make a web project which on compiling/deployment will give a war file. And i have a separate project for which the war(just the war file after bundling the project) file will be given to me.

Now my requirement is to make a EAR file comprising both my project bundle and also including the war of the other completed project. I need to use maven for this.

I know the multi-module projects can be created using maven. But i am not sure how it will handle isolated war file. I mean for my project it will have the whole structure , artifactId and groupId. What about the other war how will it be handled.

I know this may be a novice question. But can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this would typically be handled would be making the isolated WAR file a dependency. Install it in your local maven repo and just list it as a dependency in the POM for your EAR module. Also, making your WAR project a module under your EAR project would handle the WAR that you're actually building.

Comment: But i have to provide others with just the root path of my project but not my local system repository. Means i can't let other users access my System folders . They can only use the SVN access to the root of my projects.

Comment: In that case, generally, you'd want to setup a shared maven repository (using nexus or something similar) for your artifacts. Assuming this is a one-time thing for you, you this might not be the fastest solution. You could always try pulling the WAR in as an resource with maven I suppose.